# How do I find the name of the fields for an Install?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, scripting, sccm

I am trying to make an INSTALL.CMD file for a few programs.I am unsure of how to get the names of the corresponding fields.

For example lets say I'm installing Microsoft Office and it asks for a domain name, serial number, company name etc. How do I label those fields for a .CMD file?

Is there a file or document that tells you the labels for these fields?

Comment: See [Windows Installer Transform Files](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc181086.aspx) and [Create Custom Configurations, etc](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc178960.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Office products, a batch script is not the best method for customizing the install. Launch setup.exe from a command line with /admin ("setup.exe /admin") to launch the **Office Customization Tool**. It is a GUI for making the changes you want, including licensing information, company name, etc. It will save as a .msp that you put in the updates folder (or any folder you create) of the installer. You can then create a new application in SCCM (better than Packages) and use
`Setup.exe /adminfile "updates\Custom.msp"`